# Displaying some text instead of a progress bar on swipe refresh

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I wanted to display date on SwipeRefresh and i am displaying it already but i want to display last refresh date while swiping down instead of progress bar can anyone assist me how to do this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
TextView DateView;
TextView tvtitle;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_test);
    tvtitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

    DateView = findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss z");

     swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
         @Override
         public void onRefresh() {
             getDate();

             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                 }
             },1500);
         }

     });

}

public void getDate(){
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    DateView.setText(currentDateandTime);
}
}
```

want to show Last refresh date while swiping down instead of preloader or progress bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236653/android-customizing-swipe-refresh-layout

Comment: Is there a simple way to do it, i dont need a complicated one . I just wanted to display the text on replace of the progress bar

Comment: There is no public api to change icon for refresh so you should use one of that CustomSwipeRefreshLayout libraries.